# How to do packet sniffer?

Tags: packet, tcp

Everyone. This is all about our door logging system, Falco. When an employee taps his/her ID to a card reader, the signal goes to Falco server and input the data(card ID, Time) into a database. The report from Falco is really not helpful so our HR people do attendance recording job nearly manually. I have no access to the Falco database but I can physically access to a "Panel" which resides between Falco server and card reader. Can i eavesdrop a packet from the Falco Panel and put the data into my own database? Falco Panel implements TCP/IT, ARP, and DHCP and uses ports number 4413 and 4414. I searched how to use Ethernet Splitter but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the same network that Falco runs on you can use some kind of packet sniffing software.  Wireshark is a very popular packet sniffer which i would recommend.  Wireshark can record all packet traffic and sort it by the protocol used.  It allows you to save, print and add the records to a database like you are wanting to do.  However the main thing you need to do on your end is gain access to the same network falco and the card readers use.  So yes you could use an ethernet splitter and run a separate cable to your computer. That way wireshark can gain access to the traffic. You can download wireshark at http://www.wireshark.org

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add that Wireshark uses `libpcap` to actually capture packets. Once you have identified the protocol and data format, you can use it too if you want to write your own application. See http://www.tcpdump.org.